# I need to get usernames that I follow from array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So what I need to do is to get users that I follow and then do not display them.

This is my code at the moment:

This shows me the users that I follow

```
const usersFollowed = await FollowUser.find({user: req.session.user.username})
```

so when I log it I get this:

```
[ { _id: 5cd14c8cacbb164b98f389e2,
    user: 'feknaz',
    following: 'botukas',
    created_at: 'Tue May 07 2019 12:14:52 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)',
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5cd14c8eacbb164b98f389e3,
    user: 'feknaz',
    following: 'gokas',
    created_at: 'Tue May 07 2019 12:14:54 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Now I need to get only `following` value from all of these so I get data like this: `botukas, gokas`

```
usersFollowed.following
```

this returs me undefined.

And then I need to put the code in the `nin` property right here:

```
const users = await User.find({username: {$nin: usersFollowed.following}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use map function like below.

```
const users = usersFollowed.map(user => user.following);
console.log(users);
```

If you need comma(,) separated data you can use join

```
const users = usersFollowed.map(user => user.following).join(',');
```

Comment: I get `user` is undefined

Comment: Glad to hear that it works. Please mark as accept and upvote if this resolves your problem. It will help others as well.